# Why command -- sh raise error?

Tags: shell, capistrano, sh, zsh, capistrano3

Why the shell command raises error:

```
    sudo -u postgres \ 
    -- sh -c '/usr/bin/env psql -c "CREATE ROLE deploy PASSWORD secret SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE INHERIT LOGIN;"'
```

Causes:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: CREATE
              ^
```

What's right syntax ? 
Many thanks.

Comment: Please fix your formatting. Precede a line with 4 spaces for preformatted text, or use the { } icon on the editor.

Comment: @miken32 formatting makes the code in one line, it will be difficult to understand. I'll fix it a little later.

Comment: Is that the *exact* command that causes you that error? Did that come out of some script file? Does copying and pasting that from here back into the terminal still fail with that error?

Comment: @EtanReisner I run the command under root on the server manually. (Yes this is the command from deployment tool)

Comment: It seems like all the nested commands are causing a level of quoting to be lost. This can be tricky with shell quoting.

Comment: @Barmar think the same, but I also looking for a solution how to solve it =)

Comment: That first setting of the `RBENV` variables seems unlikely to be adding anything here (not that it should be hurting though). Is using `env` here at all meaningful though?

Comment: @EtanReisner for now the variables not nessesary. I think I should remove from the question even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo -u postgres '/usr/bin/env RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.3 psql -c "CREATE ROLE deploy PASSWORD secret SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE INHERIT LOGIN;"'
```

`env` takes variable assignments before the command to run. And I don't see why you need to use `sh -c`, `sudo` executes the command for you.

Comment: I can not drop `-- sh` part ;) . I think that problem in double dash, because `sh -c 'whoami'` works fine.

Comment: Think we get the point of resolving the issue ;) I will go to investigate it further ;)

Comment: The one thing i can't understand for what the double dash is present

Comment: Most commands use double dash to indicate where options end and non-option arguments begin. This is useful if you have an argument that begins with `-`, because it would look like an option. It's not needed in the above command.

Comment: And one little question: How to make work the nested quotes? Like in the folowing command `sudo -u postgres sh -c 'psql -c "CREATE ROLE deploy1 PASSWORD secret SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE INHERIT LOGIN;"'` Don't have more votes for your help ;)

Comment: The whole point of my answer was that you shouldn't use `sh -c`. If that doesn't solve the problem, please unaccept my answer because it's wrong.

Comment: Thus our deployment tool executes commands on remote server. =\

Comment: What does a remote server have to do with it? `sh` is not `ssh`.

Comment: The tool enters on the server by ssh connection and then tries to execute the shell command which I've described. Everything works well besides the command. It just written with wrong syntax, I expect.

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve that. Why did you accept my answer if it doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: I wanna go to sleep yet. Thus I'm ready to accept any answer :) No problem, just tried a luck ;) Sry for wasting time.